# Python selenium сохранение пароля

Tags: python, selenium

при login на сайте через chromedriver появляется окно с просьбой сохранить пароль, в пользовательском Chrome через настройки эту опцию отключил, как ее отключить в chromedriver? (os windows)

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.Chrome.options import Options
opt = Options()
#opt.add_agument() --Какой аргумент отключит вопрос про создание пароля?
driver = selenium.webdriver('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver', chrome_options = opt)
```

Comment: Эм.. Точно так же?

Comment: Неа, там видимо каждый раз стартует новый экземпляр с дефолтными настройками :(

Comment: Там можно папку для профиля указать - если в ней будут настройки, то они применятся.

Comment: А подскажите как, где папку указать? Че т я не в теме :(

Comment: `chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-save-password-bubble=false")`
попробуйте так.

Comment: Неа, так не получилось.Получилось через  chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir" + path), как писали выше - путь до пользовательской директории с настройками.